# Model Relation in Loopback framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, foreign-keys, loopbackjs

I want to establish a relation between two models, following the json files:

```
 {
        "name": "Surveyor",
        "plural": "surveyors",
        "base": "PersistedModel",
        "strict": true,
        "idInjection": true,
        "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "mongodb": {
        "collection": "surveyors"
    },
    "settings": {
        "mongodb": {
            "allowExtendedOperators": true
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "surname": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "dateOfBirth": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "birthPlace": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "provinceOfBirth": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "gender": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "registrationNumber": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "unique": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {}
   },
   "acls": [],
   "methods": {}
}
```

```
    {
      "name": "Dossier",
      "plural": "dossiers",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "strict": true,
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
          "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "mongodb": {
          "collection": "dossiers"
      },
      "settings": {
          "mongodb": {
              "allowExtendedOperators": true
          }
      },
      "properties": {
          "delCode": {
              "type": "string",
              "required": true
          },
          "client": {
              "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "required": true
              },
              "surname": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "required": true
              },
              "taxCode": {
                  "type": "string"
              }
          },
          "surveyor": {
              "type": "string"
          },
          "examination": {
              "type": "object"
          },
          "appointment": {
              "type": "date"
          },
          "status": {
              "type": "string",
              "required": true
          },
          "notes": {
              "type": "string"
          }
     },
     "validations": [],
     "relations": {},
     "acls": [],
     "methods": {}
}
```

One dossier can have one surveyor, as key I want to use the property `surveyor` in the Dossier Model, corresponding to the property `registrationNumber` in the Surveyor Model.

I want to query the dossier Model and obtain the surveyor data in the dossier doc:

```
[GET] /api/dossiers
```

or with a filter:

```
[GET] /api/dossiers?filter={"include":"surveyor"}
```

if it is possible I want to configure the relation in the json file, not in the code.

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [relation generator](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Relation-generator.html) to create that for you. In your case you're going to need to create a [belongsTO relation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/BelongsTo-relations.html) from Dossier to Surveyor. If you want to query the other way around (dossiers from a surveyor) you're going to need to create a hasMany relation from Surveyor to Dossier.

In short, for what you've asked, you're going to end up with something like this:

In Dossier model:

```
...
"relations": {
  "surveyor": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "Surveyor",
    "foreignKey": "surveyor",
    "primaryKey": "registrationNumber"
  }
}
...
```